# How find all MongoDB documents inserted between two LocalDateTime

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime

I'm trying to develop an app that retrive all documents inserted in a certain period.

This is my actual sample code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("eam");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("coll");

List<Document> docsList = new ArrayList<>();

LocalDateTime initDate = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime endDate = initDate.plusSeconds(5);
int i = 0;
while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(endDate)) {
    Document doc = new Document("id", i)
            .append("name objy", "Obj " + i)
            .append("timeStamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    docsList.add(doc);
    i++;
}

collection.insertMany(docsList);

MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(new Document("timestamp", new Document("$gte", endDate.minusSeconds(3)).append("$lte", endDate.minusSeconds(2)))).iterator();
try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

As @Valijo, I modified my code to filter by gte and lte but now It doesn't return anything!
Why?

Comment: https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/ if you don't want to work with timestamps

$in checks if timestamp is equals to one of the values inside the $in: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

But you need a between, this code should work for you:

```
 db.yourcollection.find({$gte: {'timestamp': min}, $lte: {'timestamp': max}})
```

please mind: the above code is for mongo shell, but you should be able to "translate" it to your needed syntax

EDIT: also mind that mongodbs time is always UTC

Answer (score 1):

`$in` selects exact values as given array.

So, you need to keep the exact `timestamp` reference (with 1 ms precision)

The problem is here:

```
LocalDateTime initDate = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime endDate = initDate.plusSeconds(5);
int i = 0;
while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(endDate)) { 
    Document doc = new Document("id", i)
            .append("name objy", "Obj " + i)
            .append("timeStamp", LocalDateTime.now()); //<-- The timestamp ms may differ from initDate ms
    docsList.add(doc);
    i++;
}
```

**Solution 1:** While inserting documents, use:

```
initDate.plusSeconds(i)
```

And then your query will return what you expect

**Solution 2:** (You may translate to your programming language)

Keep `timeStamp` references and then search them

```
var date1 = new Date(1537457334015); //Thursday, 20 September 2018 15:28:54.015
var date2 = new Date(1537457335014); //Thursday, 20 September 2018 15:28:55.014

var date3 = new Date(1537457336015); //Thursday, 20 September 2018 15:28:56.015 1 sec 1 ms
var date4 = new Date(1537457336025); //Thursday, 20 September 2018 15:28:56.025 2 sec 11 ms 

var date2Plus1Sec = new Date( date2.getTime() + 1000 );

//db.coll.remove({})

db.coll.insert([
    {
        "timeStamp" : date1
    },
    {
        "timeStamp" : date2
    },
    {
        "timeStamp" : date3
    },
    {
        "timeStamp" : date4
    }
])

db.coll.find({"timeStamp" :{$in: [date1, date2, date2Plus1Sec ]} } ).pretty();
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3bea3ba135b198e17ec2d"),
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2018-09-20T15:28:54.015Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba3bea3ba135b198e17ec2e"),
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2018-09-20T15:28:55.014Z")
}
```

So `Thursday, 20 September 2018 15:28:56.014` not exists in database

**Solution 3:** Don't use exact value match and use `$gte` and `$lte` operators to search `timeStamp` range